# How to Slice Dataframe based on two String Column Values in Pandas Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Data frame that I am importing from a SharePoint list. Within the Data frame I have a column called 'Identifier' (a text field) which separates tasks based on their hierarchy (x / x.x / x.x.x / - where x is a digit)

The df looks something like below:

```
     Task Name Assigned To                         % Complete  ...   Modified By Version                 Identifier
0    Equipment Intelligent Special Network System                    0.00  ...  Dominic Leow     1.0          1
1              Core Switch, 24SFP+8GE, Combo+4SFP                    0.00  ...  Dominic Leow     1.0        1.1
2                                         Level 1                    0.00  ...  Dominic Leow     1.0      1.1.1
3                                         Hacking                    0.30  ...  Dominic Leow     2.0    1.1.1.1
4                                      PVC Piping                    0.20  ...  Dominic Leow     2.0    1.1.1.2
5                                        Trunking                    0.45  ...  Dominic Leow     2.0    1.1.1.3
6                                         Cabling                    0.90  ...  Dominic Leow     2.0    1.1.1.4
7                                         Testing                    0.25  ...  Dominic Leow     2.0    1.1.1.5
8                                     Termination                    0.10  ...  Dominic Leow     2.0    1.1.1.6
9                                         Level 2                    0.00  ...  Dominic Leow     1.0      1.1.2
10                                        Hacking                    0.00  ...  Dominic Leow     1.0    1.1.2.1
11                                     PVC Piping                    0.00  ...  Dominic Leow     1.0    1.1.2.2
12                                       Trunking                    0.00  ...  Dominic Leow     1.0    1.1.2.3
13                                        Cabling                    0.00  ...  Dominic Leow     1.0    1.1.2.4
14                                        Testing                    0.00  ...  Dominic Leow     1.0    1.1.2.5
15                                    Termination                    0.00  ...  Dominic Leow     1.0    1.1.2.6
16                                        Level 3                    0.00  ...  Dominic Leow     1.0      1.1.3
```

I want to slice all the Rows between two Identifier column values having the format (x.x.x). For example I would want all rows between 1.1.1 until 1.1.2 along with 1.1.2 until 1.1.3 so on an so forth. The objective is to group rows between two sets of identifiers having the format (x.x.x) & save this sliced data frame into a variable, so that I can call it later and do some calculation on it while iterating the entire process.

### I have tried the below code but it doesn't seem to work

UPDATE 1 (1/28/2020) - Based on the responses I have made the 'Identifier' Column as the index and it does slice the df, but only when I provide the actual index value. The entirety of the dataset has 1000s of columns & the 'Identifier' only follows a pattern  of (x.x.x - where x is a digit) Code updated below

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

authcookie = Office365('https://speedmax.sharepoint.com', username='username', password='password').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://speedmax.sharepoint.com/sites/jdtstadium', authcookie=authcookie)
sp_list = site.List('joblist')
data = sp_list.GetListItems('All Tasks', rowlimit=5000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

stringMatch_mainTask = re.compile(r'^\d$')
stringMatch_bqItem = re.compile(r'^\d'+'.'+'\d$')
stringMatch_level = re.compile(r'^\d'+'.'+'\d'+'.'+'\d$')
stringMatch_job = re.compile(r'^\d'+'.'+'\d'+'.'+'\d'+'.'+'\d$')

mainTaskdf = df[df['Identifier'].str.contains(stringMatch_mainTask)]
bqItemdf = df[df['Identifier'].str.contains(stringMatch_bqItem)]
leveldf = df[df['Identifier'].str.contains(stringMatch_level)]
jobdf = df[df['Identifier'].str.contains(stringMatch_job)]

df = df.set_index("Identifier")
dfSlice = df["1.1.1":"1.1.2"]
print(solution)
```

Please let me know how I can find a viable solution for this? This data will fuel our custom reports so I am desperate to get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the index to identifier and just slicing from there?

Comment: So sorry to ask such a noob question but how do I exactly do that? I am really new to python (picked it up a week ago) and I am stuck at this for now 2 full days.

Comment: i can't try it out right now, but do a df.set_index("Identifier") and then just slice through the index df["1.1.1":"1.1.2"] , see if this works

Comment: and then re-slice by "1.0 ", "2.0" etc. Or try https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html multi-indexing

Comment: So I made the 'Identifier' column as the index and when I run the above code it does slice it but it only does so for the specific index value that I have provided. I want pandas to slice based on the pattern I am providing between two similar Identifier fields.

Comment: sorry for the pseudo-code :) slicing in pandas can be done so many ways, this is just an idea, i'm sure there are other easier ones. so after you slice by index, slice again by the last identifier needed .. df["1.1":"1.2"][df["indentifier2"] == "1.0"]